# In Courty and Li (2000) "Sequential Screening", what justifies the last equation in Lemma 3.2?

Tags: game-theory, economics, operations-research

Regarding the article "Sequential Screening," in Review of Economic Studies, 2000 by Courty and Li:

In Lemma 3.2, the last equality states that
$$\frac{dU(t)}{dt}=\int_{\underline{v}}^{\overline{v}}\frac{\partial g(v|t)}{\partial t}u(t,v)dv = -\int_{\underline{v}}^{\overline{v}}\frac{\partial G(v|t)}{\partial t}y(t,v)dv.$$

This (the second equality here) is an application of integration by parts (they show in Lemma 3.1 that $\frac{\partial u(t,v)}{\partial v}=y(t,v)$); but why is the antiderivative term equal to zero? That is, why does

$$\Bigl[\frac{\partial G(v|t)}{\partial t}u(t,v)\Bigr]^{\overline{v}}_{\underline{v}}=0 \ \ \ \forall t \quad ?$$

[Answered by Sergio: because of the constant support condition on $g(\cdot | t)$.]

Background: This article analyzes a direct revelation mechanism, where the agent learns and discloses information about his valuation in two stages, and the principal assigns payments and allocations after the second stage.

Notation:

$t$ and $v$ are the ex ante agent type and ex post valuation, respectively, distributed according to pdfs $f(\cdot)$ and $g(\cdot|t)$. The latter is assumed to have constant support $[\underline{v},\overline{v}]$ $\forall t$.

$G(\cdot|t)$ is the cdf corresponding to $g(\cdot|t)$.

$y(t,v)$ is the probability of allocation to agent of type $t$ with ex post valuation $v$.

$u(t,v)$ is the ex post surplus to the agent in the mechanism, assuming honest reporting of $t$ and $v$. $u(t,v) = vy(t,v)-x(t,v)$, where $x$ is the payment from the agent to the principal.

$U(t)$ is the expected surplus $\int_{\underline{v}}^{\overline{v}}u(t,v)g(v|t)dt$ of an agent of type $t$.

Comment: What kind of quantities are $G$ and $u$? Presumably they're making some assumptions as to their boundary conditions i.e. one or the other of these quantities assumed to be zero.

Comment: Is the downvote because of topic of the question, or its initial poor phrasing / lack of relevant background information? I hope it's not the former, because I really like the idea of having a venue for discussing the derivations in journal articles.

Comment: Your initial version was a bit thin, but I agree with your point: this site is meant to be useful to students and professionals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because:

1. The utility of the lowest type is being normalized to zero $u(t,\underline v)=0$ ?
2. $G(\overline v |t)=1 \,\forall t$ ?
3. $G(\underline v |t)=0\, \forall t$ ?

But it is hard to say because the question did not define what $G$ is (I am assuming is a CDF with support on $[\underline v, \overline v]$).

Comment: You're right--it's implied by the assumption that the cdf $G(v|t)$  has constant support w.r.t. $t$. I wasn't thinking clearly what that partial derivative was. So it doesn't require your first proposal, normalization. Thank you very much--I'm surprised that this venue worked, and so quickly!